# how to use Java ASM from java code to detect method?

Tags: java, eclipse, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

i am new to using ASM library.

1-i have to find number of class in code
2-which class called which method,(caller class)
3-each method called by which class

source code

```
    public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cls1 c1=new Cls1();
    Cls2 c2=new Cls2();

    c1.m2c1();
    }
```

}

public class Cls1 {

```
 int var1;
 int var2;
 String name;
 boolean bool;
 Cls1()
 {
    var1 = this.var1;
    var1 = this.var1;
    name = this.name;
    bool = this.bool;


 }
 Cls2 cl2=new Cls2();
 int z=cl2.m1c2(5,6);

 public int m1c1(int x,int y)
 {
     return x+y;
 }

 public void m2c1()
 {
     System.out.println("From m2c1  z= "+z);
 }
```

}

public class Cls2 {

```
 public int m1c2(int x,int y)
 {
     return x+y;
 }
```

}

i have no idea how i do this project ..

Comment: You don't need ASM for this - just inspect the callstack at runtime.

Comment: maybe i no need but i have to solve with ASM approach  ..

Comment: i am good in java but have no idea how use the ASM for a source code ..

Comment: [so] is not for giving tutorials, it’s not even meant to provide links to tutorials, but I think, pointing to the [official website](http://asm.ow2.org/) is fine. It contains several tutorials. Come back when you made an actual attempt and are struggling…